# How to follow the condition to underline in the table?

Tags: php, html, css

I have a question how to underline in the table according the column data. Below is example coding to explain what I am facing the problem:

I want to detect if column `underline` is 1 the first name data will draw the underline, if 0 the first name data no show the underline.  Below the sample is hardcode, if real situation, I have too many row to show the data, I cannot 1 by 1 to add `text-decoration: underline;` in the td. So that, hope someone can guide me how to solve this problem. I am using the php code to make the variable to define the underline.

```html
<!--Below the php code I just write the logic, because I don't know how to write to detect the column underline value-->
<?php
if ( <th>Underline</th> == 1) {
$add_underline = "text-decoration: underline;";
                                }
 if ( <th>Underline</th> == 0) {
$add_underline = "text-decoration: underline;";
                                }
?>
<table style="width:100%">
  <tr>
    <th>Firstname</th>
    <th>Lastname</th> 
    <th>Underline</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td style="<?php echo $add_underline;?> ">Jill</td>
    <td>Smith</td>
    <td>1</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td style="<?php echo $add_underline;?>">Eve</td>
    <td>Jackson</td>
    <td>0</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td style="<?php echo $add_underline;?>">John</td>
    <td>Doe</td>
    <td>1</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

My output like below the picture:

[image: Output1]

My expected result like below the picture, Jill and John can underline:
[image: Output2]

Comment: How are the `0`s and `1`s being determined? If it is set by a certain output from the server, then you can use PHP. Otherwise you might be better off using JS since using PHP will be a cumbersome and static approach anyway, as the data does not come from the server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not use javascript to achieve this? No matter what the server sends it will evaluate the condition if `1` is set and then underline accordingly... You would have to use classes to get the appropriate table data tags holding the values, I added `class='name'` to the names `<td>` tag and `class='underline'` tot he underline `<td>` tag.

```js
// get the values of the elements with a class of 'name'
let names = document.getElementsByClassName('name');
// get the values of the elements with a class of 'underline'
let underline = document.getElementsByClassName('underline');
// loop over elements using for and use the keys to get and set values
// `i` will iterate until it reaches the length of the list of elements with class of underline
for(let i = 0; i < underline.length; i++){
  // use the key to get the text content and check if 1 is set use Number to change string to number for strict evaluation
  if(Number(underline[i].textContent) === 1){
      // set values set to 1 to underline in css style
      names[i].style.textDecoration = "underline";
  }
}
```

```html
<table style="width:100%">
  <tr>
    <th>Firstname</th>
    <th>Lastname</th> 
    <th>Underline</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="name">Jill</td>
    <td>Smith</td>
    <td class='underline'>1</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="name">Eve</td>
    <td>Jackson</td>
    <td class='underline'>0</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="name">John</td>
    <td>Doe</td>
    <td class='underline'>1</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Or using the td child values...

```js
let tr = document.querySelectorAll("tr");
last = null;
for(let i = 1; i < tr.length; i++){
  if(Number(tr[i].lastElementChild.innerHTML) === 1){
      tr[i].firstElementChild.style.textDecoration = "underline";
  }
}
```

```html
<table style="width:100%">
  <tr>
    <th>Firstname</th>
    <th>Lastname</th> 
    <th>Underline</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Jill</td>
    <td>Smith</td>
    <td>1</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Eve</td>
    <td>Jackson</td>
    <td>0</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>John</td>
    <td>Doe</td>
    <td>1</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Thanks Mr. Genius.